# Unnest list of dictionaries to key value and subdicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a dict with nested lists of dictionaries, as below:

```
{'data1': [{'data2': 'value2'},
  {'data3': [{'data4': 'value4'},
    {'data5': [{'data6': 'value6'}, {'data7': 'value7'}]}]}]}
```

I want to obtain:

```
{'data1': {'data2': 'value2',
  'data3': {'data4': 'value4',
   'data5': {'data6': 'value6', 'data7': 'value7'}}}}
```

So there are 2 tasks, convert single sub dicts to `key:value` (`{'data2':'value2'}` to `'data2':'value2'`) and convert lists of dicts to nested dicts (`{'data5': [{'data6':'value6'},{'data7' : 'value7'}]}` to `'data5': {'data6':'value6','data7' : 'value7'}`).

This is a deeply nested recursive dictionary with multiple levels.

I was trying something like this:

```
def flat(j): 
    if not isinstance(j, (dict, list)): 
        return j 
    if isinstance(j, dict): 
        p=list(j.values()) 
        f=list(j.keys()) 
        tipo=type(p[0]).__name__ 
        if tipo=="str": 
             (Do something) 
    if isinstance(j, list): 
        return [flat(v) for v in j] 
    return {k: flat(v) for k, v in j.items()}
```

in order to flat the single dictionaries but I found the problem of deletting the sub dict and add the key:value. For sure there is another post with how to convert the list to nested dictionaries

Comment: Was there a particular problem with the code you have tried?

Comment: Is the nesting branched? If yes, can you provide an example? What happens if you have duplicated keys (ex. data6 == data7)?

Comment: @mkrieger I was trying somthing like this:
def flat(j):
    if not isinstance(j, (dict, list)):
        return j
    if isinstance(j, dict):
        p=list(j.values())
        f=list(j.keys())
        tipo=type(p[0]).__name__
        if tipo=="str":
   (Do something)
    if isinstance(j, list):
        return [flat(v) for v in j]
    return {k: flat(v) for k, v in j.items()}
in order to flat the single dictionaries but I found the problem of deletting the sub dict and add the key:value.
For sure there is another post with how to convert the list to nested dictionaries

Comment: don't post large code as comment, edit the question ;)

Comment: @nozway In fact there are duplicated keys but under different subdictionaries, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive approach and handle each value depending on whether this is a `dict`, `list`, or something else:

```
def unnest(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return {k: unnest(v) for k,v in x.items()}
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return {k:unnest(v) for e in x for k,v in unnest(e).items()}
    else:
        return x

# assuming the input dictionary as "d"
unnest(d)
```

output:

```
{'data1': {'data2': 'value2',
           'data3': {'data4': 'value4',
                     'data5': {'data6': 'value6', 'data7': 'value7'}
                     },
           },
}
```

*NB. the requirement here is that lists only contain dictionaries, if not you need to add a condition*

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, and sorry, I have less than 15 of reputation for voting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
data = {'data1': [{'data2': 'value2'}, {'data3': [{'data4': 'value4'}, {'data5': [{'data6': 'value6'}, {'data7': 'value7'}]}]}]}
def unnest(d):
  if isinstance(d, list):
    yield from [j for k in d for j in unnest(k)]
  else:
    for a, b in d.items():
       yield (a, b if not isinstance(b, (list, dict)) else dict(unnest(b)))

result = dict(unnest(data))
```

Output:

```
{'data1': {'data2': 'value2', 'data3': {'data4': 'value4', 'data5': {'data6': 'value6', 'data7': 'value7'}}}}
```

This will work on both lists and dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will search about the yield command. But without return command there is no result. Anyway thanks , and sorry, I have less than 15 of reputation for voting.